# merging data and receiving a big loss of data

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I've been preparing my data and somehow I have way less data after merging my data sets.

Since I don't have the longitude and latitude in my data I've been using the following code after I downloaded the package **zipcode** (`tel1` is my data containing zipcodes)

```
merge <- merge(zipcode,tel1,by.x=c('zip'),by.y=c('zip_code'))
```

Before merging I had 195956 observations, while after merging it dropped down to 180090, but I don't understand why.

In my opinion I just merged them where `zip` was equal to `zip_code` and I added the information from the dataset zipcode to my folder tel1

Afterward I wanted to remove the rows that contain NA because the merge couldn't define any numbers or whatever. I used this code

```
final <- result[complete.cases(result),]
```

Then my number of observations dropped down to 51006 which I just can't believe. There can't be so many mismatches in my data.

Is there any other code that I should use?

Afterwards I've been trying to delete the duplicates with the code

```
 last <- with(final,final[order(state,latitude,longitude),])
```

but the number of observations was consistent (51006).

What did I do wrong or is there a way to get my data into an excel file again after merging the data so I could manually check if there are really so many mismatches?
Thanks

Comment: Try using `join` from the plyr package, it's much more intuitive than merge.

Comment: you can also look at the `all` argument to `merge`.  `merge(zipcode, tel1, by.x='zip', by.y='zip_code', all.y=TRUE)`

Comment: thanks @Justin this worked out no loss at all but if I go on with final<- result[complete.cases(result),]
to remove the NA it till drops down to 51006 any solution for that?

Comment: We can't fix the problem of there being NA values in your data. If there is an NA value in any column, using `complete.cases` will drop the entire row. Perhaps there was a problem in reading in the data that generated missing values where there shouldn't be...?

Comment: good point there are some rows that contain NA because my data is incomplete. How can I manage to just drop the NA out of the columns latitude & longitude

Comment: Try `complete.cases(result[,c('latitude','longitude')])` instead.

Comment: Try playing with `na.omit` and `is.na` to deal with (or modify) those annoying rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can use the `all` argument to `merge`.

```
merge(zipcode, tel1, by.x='zip', by.y='zip_code', all.y=TRUE)
```

However, for rows where matches aren't found in the zipcode data, there will be `NA`s. Thus if you then `na.rm` or something to that effect, you will wind up with the same "data loss"

Check the zip codes for the rows where there are NAs in the lat and long columns after the merge:

```
tel1[is.na(tel1$latitude) | is.na(tel1$longitude),]
```

My guess is they aren't valid zip codes or the list of zipcodes you have is not complete.

Comment: I gues the zipcodes are fine my data just consists another column where many NA are due to there is no information for that. that's why I should just delete the rows where longitude and latitude have an NA. If I try the code final<-complete.cases(result[,c('latitude','longitude')]) I don't get a new dataset like before I get values

Comment: thanks I got it just removed the lists out of the excel file before entering it into R ;)